# Is there a true counterpart to Control-E in vim?

Tags: vim

In Vim, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> is normally used to scroll the window up, and it can keep scrolling the window to the point where the bottom edge of the file goes above the bottom edge of the window.

This enables us to center the bottom of a file in the middle of our window, allowing for easier viewing.

Unfortunately, the advertised counterpart, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> , does not appear to be able to scroll the window down to the point where the top edge of file is in the middle of our window, allowing for easier viewing of the top of the file.

Is there some mechanism in Vim that would allow us to move to the top edge of the file to the middle of the window for easy viewing?

Comment: Are you on windows? On windows environment, vim maps Ctrl-Y to redo.

Comment: @DJ., Ubuntu Linux. Control-Y works correctly until you get to the top of the file.

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless you hack vim.

Comment: You could potentially script something that created and resized a split appropriately, but the end result would be ugly. Note also that you can set `scrolloff` to a very large number if you generally want the current line in the middle of the screen (but again, by design, that doesn't scroll down the very top of the file).

Comment: You could look into the internals of [goyo-vim](https://github.com/junegunn/goyo.vim) which shows a lot of whitespace at the top of the buffer